# Javascript many calls onselect

Tags: javascript

I am ashamed to ask for it but on the line onSelect, I can't call updateCoords and showPreview. I don't know the syntax ...

```
$('#cropbox').Jcrop({

  aspectRatio: 1,
  onSelect: updateCoords showPreview,
  onChange: showPreview

});
```

Thanks for your help and pardon my french

Answer (score 2):

If they are just functions, call them like this:

```
$('#cropbox').Jcrop({
  aspectRatio: 1,
  onSelect: function(){
      updateCoords(); 
      showPreview();
  },
  onChange: showPreview
});
```